# Why should i transform strings on my csv file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I got an error on spyder ide like

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

and i couldnt transform lines into integer.
So, here is my code

```
veri = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\batuc\Desktop\CC GENERAL.csv")
X = veri.drop(["BALANCE","PURCHASES"],axis=1)
net = sps.somNet(40,40, X.values, PBC=True )
net.train(0.01,10000)
hrt = np.array((net.project(X.values)))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, max_iter=300, random_state=0)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(hrt)
veri["kümeler"] = kmeans.labels_
print(veri[veri["kümeler"]==0].head(5))
print(veri[veri["kümeler"]==1].head(5))
print(veri[veri["kümeler"]==2].head(5))
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
```

Which line should i transform into integer?

And my csv file is
[image: CSV FILE]

Comment: please produce a sample reproducible data to try the above

Comment: @Roxy What do you mean by producing a repeatable sample data? sorry i am newbie

Comment: You're asking why, you're asking which one, or what are you asking? Please, read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to correct this one and make it easy to get help and solve your problem.

Comment: Try to produce sample data from your CSV file, such that we can reproduce the issue and resolve it

Comment: Your first data row contains text (maybe part of the header line?)

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be that you are reading the header as well on `pd.read_csv` which contains the symbol `-` and also is of type `str`.

Instead, you could try the following on reading the `csv` file:

Setting the header to `None`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\batuc\Desktop\CC GENERAL.csv", header=None)
```

Or by skipping the header row:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\batuc\Desktop\CC GENERAL.csv", skiprows=1)
```